Does my talaq take effect when ive uttered in a moment of feeling compelled emotionally and did not want this divorce but due to this state of anger,
I divorced my wife while walking with her in the street. She said something distasteful to me. My anger escalated, she didn't also try and calm me down, by explaining herself. This angered me more and I tried calming myself and refraining from saying things that I did not want , but the anger got the better of me and made me utter talaq to her.
Can you provide an answer that I can pass onto her as she is curious to the answers. I've got no local imam to assist in this matter. If a call can be done with the both of us.
Shukran

Salam and welcome to islamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As for the topic of talaq you must be aware that questions on these topic require facce to face situation of the husband with a well-versed scholar who can qualify whether talaq took place or not. We are not a fatwa site we can only provide information about topic of Islam.

We are not a fatwa site. If there is no local mufti then call one on telephone or travel to meet one. Divorce is nearly always given in anger no one gives divorce when he is amused with his wife. Majority of the scholars state that divorce in anger is enforced.
